# jQuery Simpletip which dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, simpletip

I have the script:

```
$('#download').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please right-click and select "Save As".');
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

I need to have a similar script that will append a simpletip popup to the link (This plugin here [SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/)). As the element with the id #download is created after the dom initially loads.

This is how simpletip is activated:

```
$("JQUERY SELECTOR").simpletip();
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

If you can link me to or suggest another way of doing this with the 'hover' event that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility you have is to call

```
$('#download').simpletip();
```

after you created that element.

Comment: How would i do that because it is created within a lightbox using the lightbox plugin

Comment: @FraserK: Mmh are you sure that lightbox generates this element dynamically? To me it seems it would not do such a thing.

Comment: yes it does, when a lightbox linked element is clicked lightbox appends its necessary html to the body and then removes it on close.

Comment: @FraserK: Ok if you say so (I couldn't find any option that lets you specify the ID of the box, but maybe you are using another lightbox--kind-of plugin). If the plugin you are using does not provide any callback mechanism that lets you call a function once the box is created, the only chance is to look for another similar plugin which provides this.

Comment: I had a thought. Is there a way to detect when content is added to the dom?

Comment: @FraserK: There exist events, but is not recommend to use them and  they are supported by all browsers. Which plugin do you use? This one? http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: Yes it was that one. I am just about to try editing the plugin, ill let you know how i go.

Comment: @FraserK: If possible, you can use Fancybox (http://fancybox.net/) which provides possibilities to register callbacks.

Comment: I already have this in place and editing the plugin works fine, thanks for the help :)